# Best idea to create this XML structure in python Dictionary

Tags: python, xml, list, dictionary

I have a data sets in a xml format and would like to store this in a Python dictionary/List and how I can iterate back. Please note the url tags will vary based on application.
Much appreciated

```
    <application name = "ap1">
        <dashboards name="">
        <title>Head</title>
            <duration>20</duration>
            <urls>
                <url>ur1-l</url>
                    :::
                <url>url-n</url>
            </urls>
        </dashboards>
</application>
```

Comment: Why do you need a dictionary? You can parse and iterate using XPath

Comment: Use an XML parsing library

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [lxml](http://lxml.de/) packageto do this :

```
from lxml import etree

# Create the schema:
with open(xsd_file) as f:
    xmlschema_doc = etree.parse(f)
xmlschema = etree.XMLSchema(xmlschema_doc)

# Create a tree for the XML doc :
doc = etree.parse(xml_text)

# Validate the XML :
return c
```

And **if you want you to see exception** try this one :

```
xmlschema.assertValid(doc)
```

inside of :

```
return xmlschema.validate(doc)
```

Comment: Thanks, For some reason the lxm is link is not working, but thanks for the idea, I was able to parse it using xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

Comment: There is no `lxm` package but `lxml`. The missing last l fixed URL.